# query with foreach loop

Tags: loops, yii, active-directory

I want to execute this query in a foreach loop to use the table in the elemant orWhere Requette (depending on the number of array elements).

```
 foreach ( $mesDeparts as $mesDepart) 
                        {
                            $holidays_rh_test = holidaystate::find()
                            ->leftJoin('holidays', '`holidays`.`id` = `holidayState`.`holiday_id`')
                            ->leftJoin('user', '`user`.`id` = `holidays`.`user_id`')
                            ->leftJoin('space_membership', '`user`.`id` = `space_membership`.`user_id`')
                            // ->where(['holidayState.user_id'=>0, 'holidayState.user_position_id'=>0, 'holidayState.stat'=>'2'])
                            ->where(['space_membership.space_id'=>$mesDepart->space_id])
                            ->andFilterWhere(['or',['holidayState.user_id'=>Yii::$app->user->id,'holidayState.user_position_id'=>$user_position->id ],['holidayState.user_id'=>0, 'holidayState.user_position_id'=>0, 'holidayState.stat'=>'2']])
                            ->orderBy('holiday_id DESC')
                            ->all();
                        }
```

Comment: Are you using yii1 or yii2?

Comment: I use yii2 framework

Comment: And what is exactly the problem? What have you already tried?

Comment: I want to use `-> where ([ 'space_membership.space_id' => $ mesDepart-> space_id]) // element 1
-> OrWhere ([ 'space_membership.space_id' => $ mesDepart-> space_id]) // element 2
-> OrWhere ([ 'space_membership.space_id' => $ mesDepart-> space_id]) // element n`

orWhere is based on the number of iteration of the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are repeating the query

You should build an  array and use in clause

```
foreach ( $mesDeparts as $key =>$mesDepart)  {
     $my_array[$key] =  $mesDepart->space_id;
}
$holidays_rh_test = holidaystate::find()
    ->leftJoin('holidays', '`holidays`.`id` = `holidayState`.`holiday_id`')
    ->leftJoin('user', '`user`.`id` = `holidays`.`user_id`')
    ->leftJoin('space_membership', '`user`.`id` = `space_membership`.`user_id`')
    ->andFiilterWhere(['in', 'space_membership.space_id', $my_array])
    ->orderBy('holiday_id DESC')
    ->all();
```